# How to config writing direction from right to left in tinyMce with impresspages plugin

Tags: tinymce, impresspages

I try to update tinyMce plugin to be able writing from right to left (like Arabic,Urdu,Persian) .

So i found this code in tinyMce support

```
tinymce.init({

directionality : 'rtl',

});
```

**The problem is that i don't found where i can add this lines ?**

So what is the file to edit this issue

Wait for you answer ... Thank you

Comment: This will be added to the default configuration of TinyMCE in 4.2.9 version https://github.com/impresspages/ImpressPages/issues/627

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the documentation about TinyMCE configuration in ImpressPages - http://www.impresspages.org/docs/tinymce

And example plugins to get you started - http://market.impresspages.org/plugins/?q=tinymce
Download any of it, check how it's built and change to your needs.

Comment: Yes its works, i turn it on to support right to left: 


- For the default settings it was just edit `Ip/Internal/Core/assets/tinymce/default.js`

and add : `directionality : 'rtl',`  over `ipTinyMceConfig = function ()`


- For update the pluging FullTinyMCE [http://market.impresspages.org/plugins/FullTinyMCE][1]


  [1]: http://market.impresspages.org/plugins/FullTinyMCE

i edited the file `Plugin/TinyMceComplete/assets/tinymcecomplete.js`

and add this line : `tinyMceDefault.directionality = 'rtl';`

Answer (score 0):

Yes its works, i turn it on to support right to left:

- For the default settings it was just edit `Ip/Internal/Core/assets/tinymce/default.js`

and add : `directionality : 'rtl',`  over `ipTinyMceConfig = function ()`

- For update the pluging FullTinyMCE http://market.impresspages.org/plugins/FullTinyMCE

i edited the file `Plugin/TinyMceComplete/assets/tinymcecomplete.js`

and add this line : `tinyMceDefault.directionality = 'rtl';`